# Sitecore 'silent' mode for Item creation and deletions

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 130404)

Sitecore Item.Editing.EndEdit() API has a 'silent' mode as a parameter. This prevents the item edit operation being recorded in the history table so the indexer doesn't get overloaded with items we don't want to be indexed.

My question is, is there a 'silent' mode for Template.CreateItemFrom() and Item.Delete() methods? Or is it possible to achieve this in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `EventDisabler()` in a using block around your code. Described (among other places) here: http://www.partechit.nl/nl/blog/2012/12/temporarily-disable-events-through-the-sitecore-api